# The "VerifyTaskFailed" task failed unexpectedly in Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, task, nuget-package

The Xamarin Android after updating nuget packages, getting this error.
Any way solve this.

> /Users/hmspl/Documents/GitHub/xamarin/packages/Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.28.0.0.2/build/monoandroid90/Xamarin.Android.Support.Annotations.targets(9,9):
>   Error MSB4018: The "VerifyVersionsTask" task failed unexpectedly.
>   System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for
>   'Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.NugetPackages' threw an exception.
>   ---> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 28   at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].TryInsert (TKey
>   key, TValue value, System.Collections.Generic.InsertionBehavior
>   behavior) [0x002b5] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs:677
>   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue].Add (TKey key,
>   TValue value) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/mono-x64/external/corefx/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Collections/Generic/Dictionary.cs:240
>   at Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.NugetPackages..cctor ()
>   [0x0006b] in :0     --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---   at
>   Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.VerifyVersionsTask.Execute ()
>   [0x0009d] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute
>   () [0x00023] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:573
>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask
>   (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x002a9]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:810
>   at Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.VerifyVersionsTask.Execute ()
>   [0x0009d] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute
>   () [0x00023] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:573
>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask
>   (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x002a9]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:810
>   at Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.VerifyVersionsTask.Execute ()
>   [0x0009d] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute
>   () [0x00023] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:573
>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask
>   (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x002a9]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:810
>   at Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.VerifyVersionsTask.Execute ()
>   [0x0009d] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute
>   () [0x00023] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:573
>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask
>   (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x002a9]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:810
>   at Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.VerifyVersionsTask.Execute ()
>   [0x0009d] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute
>   () [0x00023] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:573
>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask
>   (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x002a9]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:810
>   at Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.VerifyVersionsTask.Execute ()
>   [0x0009d] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute
>   () [0x00023] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:573
>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask
>   (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x002a9]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:810
>   at Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.VerifyVersionsTask.Execute ()
>   [0x0009d] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute
>   () [0x00023] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:573
>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask
>   (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x002a9]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:810
>   at Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.VerifyVersionsTask.Execute ()
>   [0x0009d] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute
>   () [0x00023] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:573
>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask
>   (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x002a9]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:810
>   at Xamarin.Android.Support.BuildTasks.VerifyVersionsTask.Execute ()
>   [0x0009d] in :0    at
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute
>   () [0x00023] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/TaskExecutionHost/TaskExecutionHost.cs:573
>   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask
>   (Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.Logging.TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskHost taskHost,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ItemBucket bucket,
>   Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask) [0x002a9]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/build-package-osx-mono/2019-02/external/bockbuild/builds/msbuild-15/src/Build/BackEnd/Components/RequestBuilder/TaskBuilder.cs:810
>   (MSB4018) (MMHRC.Droid)

Comment: Downgrade `28.0.0.2` to `28.0.0.1` , something they changed is breaking projects (new or old), I have not have time to investigate or report a bug....

Comment: yah ! Correct, works thanks

Comment: theres a ticket for it already https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/issues/176

Comment: That answer also posted by me! Lol

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Downgrade Package version 28.0.0.2 to 28.0.0.1 , something they changed is breaking projects

Comment: unfortunately this isn't the solution for all. 28.0.0.2 isn't available anymore and with 28.0.0.1 I have the same issue.

Anyone with another solution? I've tried so many things already, without luck.

Comment: 28.0.0.2 have some issue in package.i have no time to find solution. maybe they updating package

Comment: Yes they removed 28.0.0.2. Only the 1-version is available. I checked the repo and there is a new version available for some days now but not as package (yet).